# Stark level manifold

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, laser, fiber-optics, photonics

In this figure from https://www.rp-photonics.com/effective_transition_cross_sections.html:[image: https://www.rp-photonics.com/effective_transition_cross_sections.html]

When a high energy photon (920nm) is absorbed followed by phonon emission to lower energy level in the manifold, How does that make absorption weaker at that frequency?

Comment: Please add in a suitable reference for where the figure comes from, as it is essential for context. **Always**.